# How to scale lame-output of multiple .wav files to the same output volume

Tags: lame

When I play a number of .mp3 files the volume changes significantly sometimes. What parameters should I use to scale multiple .wav files to the same output volume

Comment: You might use application `normalize-audio` to first normalize your `.wav`files, or after conversion to mp3 to set "a relative volume adjustment frame in their ID3 tags" (see `man normalize-audio`).

Comment: There are `--replay-gain-` options in `lame`, but they set the `replay-gain`ID3 TAG, which is "not widely supported and I think it has been superseded by RVA2 in ID3v2.4" (http://id3.org/Replay%20Gain%20Adjustment).